# How to make a heat distortion effect?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light, smoke-simulation

How can I make a [heat distortion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirage#Heat_haze) effect, like you might see around the exhaust of a jet engine?

Comment: I *think* this was the 5000th question :D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Simulation

Unfortunately since it's not yet possible to [vary the IOR inside an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8113/599), it can't be simulated completely.

However, you can at least use a smoke simulation to distort things based on simulated airflow.

1. Create a fire simulation where the hot air should be. It doesn't have to be very high resolution:

   [image]
2. Move the domain to an empty layer (e.g. layer 2), then setup a material for it with some random noise:

   [image]

   This will result in something like this, which we can use to distort the rest of the scene:

   [image]
3. Create a new renderlayer and set it to mask the layer the main scene. Also set the main scene renderlayer to exclude the smoke:

   [image] [image]

   Note that I set the number of samples taken for the smoke render layer to 1, and disabled the main passes (using only the emission pass).
4. Then setup the composite nodes:

   [image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Old tutorial fromblender guru.   http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-create-heat-distortion/#.VFRCLhnD_qA

Comment: There is also one over at blendercookie. https://cgcookie.com/blender/2014/04/03/creating-heat-distortion-effects-blender/

Comment: Whoop whoop! Hooray, 100k 