# How to setup a heat haze effect in the compositor

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I am working on a desert animation and need heat haze for it. I found a [tutorial about heat haze](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-create-heat-distortion/#.VI7wnyvF9jJ). But the render layer is different from mine. The tutorial used a picture scene render layer and a heat distortion render layer in the compositor.

[image]

While mine doesn't ause image for it.
[image: My desert blend.]

What should I do?

Comment: It sounds like you want help resolving some problems in the compositor. Could you explain what was happening and why it wasn't what you wanted? In your .blend it seems you haven't set up all the nodes yet.

Comment: I'd recommend watching the rest of the tutorial. That second image is another renderlayer which outputs a random noise pattern which is used to displace the first scene (IIRC all of this is explained in that tutorial). There are several other ways this could be done however, so I might add an answer if this post is re-opened. Also see this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18296/599