# Creating Bullet Trail in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Hey People how do they create this Trail Behind the Bullet in particular games where a slow motion effect is shown.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdGHEN6FumU

Answer (score 4):

Its created by vector-displacing pixels in post-production. The game engine does this with pixel shaders in post-production too.

Check this its related: [How to make a heat distortion effect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18296/how-to-make-a-heat-distortion-effect)

You just don't need a particle simulation for the trail but a single texture behind the bullet will do.

This will create a spherical ball-like distorsion:

[image]

Smear it and adjust it in your favourite 2D application to create some water-like wave effect.

- Red channel affects the X position
- Green channel affects the Y position
- Pixel value of 0.5 is no change, brighter is positive direction, darker is negative
- Leave blue channel black

You can also sculpt the effect on a plane and bake it into a normal map. Then erase the blue channel from that map.