# Advanced Bullet Trail in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How can one simulate a real bullet distortion effect in Cycles, like in this image:

[image]

I'm mainly concerned about that funky trailing directly behind the bullet. This image is a [shadowgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowgraph) of a supersonic bullet, and not directly visible, but I was wondering about adding that Hollywood factor by having a three-dimensional distortion trailing behind the bullet.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You will want to use the smoke sim....

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Interesting... that might work. I was wondering about using a fluid sim actually, since there is a collision object piercing through a volume. Hmmm, I think some experimentation is in order.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I have this to report - initial experiments have proven unsuccessful. I used accurate size and time, so maybe it is possible using exaggerated scales or something. But based on what I've tried so far, fluid sim is not looking promising for this one. I think it's because current ripples that are beneath the water's surface show up as… nothing at all when rendered! It's obvious in hindsight.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18296/599

Comment: That looks quite interesting, Gandalf— I think I'll give that a try, maybe tweak it a bit, up the resolution & etc.