# How to create the distortion of Gas Fumes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, particles, shaders

I want to know how to simulate gas that doesn't look like pure smoke. Like the gas one might see coming out the side of a pipe or on a really hot day in the desert. I don't know how to explain it: gas without the smoke.

Comment: When asking questions like this it helps if you show an image as reference. Do you mean Heat Distortion?
 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65726/heat-distortion-effect-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18296/how-to-make-a-heat-distortion-effect and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59166/how-to-create-a-heat-distortion-effect-with-a-cycles-procedural-node-set-up-wi or  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/is-it-possible-to-change-the-ior-inside-a-volume/19298#19298 or even  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/

Comment: yes https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59166/how-to-create-a-heat-distortion-effect-with-a-cycles-procedural-node-set-up-wi this here is what I was trying to figure out!

Comment: feel free  cegaton to write an answer to this in your own words so I can vote it best :D thanks for the help so I guess I was looking for how to do heat distortion and not gas.

Comment: this one is also helpful https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18296/how-to-make-a-heat-distortion-effect